# RuntimeError while retriving data from sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert and retrieve data from database in eclipse using sqlite, but it shows a `RuntimeError`. I create a layout with three edit texts and one button to create simple information from but nothing is created. I create java database with the following code:

```
package com.example.databasetest;



import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "teacher";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "teacher_table";

    private static final String NAME = "teacher_name";
    private static final String FATHER_NAME = "father_name";
    private static final String MOTHER_NAME = "mother_name";

    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Context ctx;



    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "DATABASE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        data=db;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MOTHER_NAME + " INTEGER,"
                + ");");
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "TABLE CREATED");


    }
     public void open() throws SQLException
     {
         DBHelper db1 = new DBHelper(ctx);
            data = db1.getWritableDatabase();
     }

     public void close()
     {
         data.close();
     }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXCEPTION EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);       
    }
    public void onInsert(DBHelper db,String name,String f_name, String m_name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sql= db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("teacher_name",name);
        cv.put("father_name", f_name);
        cv.put("mother_name", m_name);
        sql.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "ONE ROW INSERTED.....");
    }

}
```

AND java file as...

```
package com.example.databasetest;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText NAME,FATHER,MOTHER,ID;
    String name,father,mother,id;
    int i=1;
    Button save;
    Context ctxx;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        FATHER=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.father_name);
        MOTHER=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mother_name);
        ID=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emp_id);


        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id=ID.getText().toString();
                name=NAME.getText().toString();
                father=FATHER.getText().toString();
                mother=MOTHER.getText().toString();

                if(id.equals(i))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not allow insertion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(ctxx);
                DB.open();
                DB.onInsert(DB, name, father, mother);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "insertion sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

and its show run time error when i click on button as in log cat..

```
05-08 02:54:05.932: D/AndroidRuntime(922): Shutting down VM
05-08 02:54:05.999: W/dalvikvm(922): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.example.databasetest.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:22)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.example.databasetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-08 02:54:06.189: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 02:54:09.589: I/Process(922): Sending signal. PID: 922 SIG: 9
```

Comment: your `ctxx` has not been initialize. try `DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: if it is useful accept or upvote.

Answer (score 2):

`ctxx` is never initialzed, and this probably the cause of the crash. Generally speaking, when you deal with Activity and Fragment subclass, you almost never need to keep a reference to the Context. Activity is a subclass of `Context`, and usually `this` is enough. In a Fragment you can retrieve the context of the `Activity` hosting the Fragment with `getActivity()`

Chante

```
 DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(ctxx);
```

with

```
DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

As @DerGolem pointed out, you are using the type INTEGER for the column `MOTHER_NAME`. Probably you want to use `TEXT`, instead, and you will also need a the primary key `"_id"`

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT"
                + ");");
```

Comment: @Blackbelt you should remove the ',' ... its a table creation

Comment: how i retrieve data froom one table to another table

Comment: please feel free to ask a new question,

Answer (score 0):

In your activity initialize the ctxx in onCreate:

ctxx=this;

or

DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

whenever you will initialize database object will null you will get sqlite locked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Also fixe this

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        data=db;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT"
                + ");");
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "TABLE CREATED");


    }
```

for  `"INTEGER,"` remove ,.

and intialise it like this DBHelper.

```
DBHelper DB=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need init ctxx in onCreate() method:

```
ctxx = this;
```

If you want to know more about sqlite on android -> ok. But if you want to less code you can try some SqliteLibrary for android. (example ActiveAndroid, GreenDAO.....).